# Show that the sum of the random variables converges absolutely almost surely for given conditions.

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, expected-value, absolute-convergence, almost-everywhere

Here is my question and here is my partial solution.

[image]

I am uncertain if I proved the hint correctly, and I am basically stuck now after proving the hint. I have seen a solution to a similar question on Math Stack Exchange, but there are some differences that I don't think I can use the same steps. Furthermore, another solution I have come across is using the Basic Inequality, which was never covered in my class.

If my proof is wrong for the hint, then please correct it for me. Furthermore, it will also be great if you can provide some solutions or hints to answer the question completely. I was thinking of using the Chebyshev's or Markov's inequalities (including their variants), but I can't seem to conclude the answer.

Comment: Last line - should be $\le$ not $=$.  Need to use $\sum \mu_n$ converges also.

Comment: oh yes, you are right about the last line for sure. Not really sure how to use $\sum \mu_n$ converges also though.

Comment: $E(|\sum(|X_n|)\le E(|\sum\mu_n|)+E(\sum(|X_n-\mu_n|)$  RHS tails $\to 0$.

Comment: Sorry, I did not quite catch that inequality you wrote in the last comment. There were multiple $\left| \cdot \right|$ placed in irregular spots.

Comment: Should be sum over triangle inequality.  Detail for $\mu_n$ and $X_n$ of opposite sign needs to be worked out.  The main point is that the tails $\to 0$ give the result you want.

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much.